# Search doesn't find tags or categories in custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, tags, categories

I've added tags and categories to a custom post, but the search bar doesn't find them when I use it. It does find the 'uncategorized' category (default category) that's inherent in wordpress though. The Categories I've entered show up in the sidebar, as well as w/the custom post type (as do the tags I've entered).

What am I missing?

Comment: Any public queryable post types should already be included in the search, unless custom code or a plugin is intercepting search queries and modifying query parameters(or your custom post type is not [`public`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments)).

Comment: Where is a plugin for solve your problem
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cat-post-type/